# Where can I buy a hunter's license?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, merchandise

Is there a shop or site you can buy a *Hunter x Hunter* license from? I have looked on Amazon, but I could not find one close to the one in anime or manga.

Answer (score 1):

Using the search term `hxh hunter license prop` I've managed to find multiple websites selling it, including Amazon, which seem to closely match the card as shown in the series.

- [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BC6NNK4H)
- [Joom](https://www.joom.com/en/products/609def52bac86e01fb22baa2)
- [Ali Express](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001566430803.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2nld)
- [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/134483791077)

As I don't have any personal experience with these particular sellers I cannot vouch for any quality. So be sure to apply some scrutiny before purchasing any of these products.